# Reformat Non Standard Date Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column of dates, however there are all in the format YYYYMMDD, ex 20141101. When I select that column, I would like the data to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I would like this to happen simultaneously during the query if possible without having to do an update statement.

Comment: DateTime should *not* have a format. You should always use the appropriate data type for the schema. To store a DateTime there is a data type called DateTime (or DateTime2) that should be used, *not* varchar/char. If you had done that it makes everything much easier. You can perform equality checks, range checks, extract date parts, etc using the built in functions. It also allows for instant integrity checks (ie. 2018-02-30 would throw an error). If you can update the table's schema. Add a nullable DateTime column, copy the data into that column, get rid of the old column, rename new column.

Comment: Sorry, Im simply extracting the data and the data in the date column is a varchar, just trying to reformat it so I can compare that column to something else

Comment: What is the end destination? Another table? Code? If it is anything other than txt output for a person then return it as a DateTime type.

Comment: I would like JOIN the two tables together and in the WHERE part put where the dates do not match , but cannot currently do that because one date column is in the format YYYYMMDD and the other in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: What is the column `type` for the other table? Is it `Date` (or also varchar)?

Comment: Both are varchar

Comment: (one more rant) this is exactly why the type system exists. If there was no reason to use types we would just have "the string". Create your schemas with the types in mind... always.

Comment: That said the easiest thing to do now to join the values is to get rid of the `-` in the date values that have them. This is less code then adding them to the dates that do have them. That will allow for a join between the 2 tables. See [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I'm with @Igor on using REPLACE on the string with dashes, mostly because it's less typing. Performance on joins with string functions is going to be poor no matter what, so might as well use one that's easier to read & write.

Comment: But that said, I'm going to rant a little, too. We, as a community, are pretty quick to jump on anyone who posts a question involving poorly typed data, and dates are probably the worst offenders. But there always seems to be this underlying assumption that the developer can change the table schema. How many of us, though, work or consult on systems that are handed down to us and are so hopeless entrenched that a schema change just isn't realistic? A lot, I'd wager. Maybe we should start cutting each other some slack on this one.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like JOIN the two tables together and in the WHERE part put where the dates do not match , but cannot currently do that because one date column is in the format YYYYMMDD and the other in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

The easiest thing to do now to join the values is to get rid of the `-` in the date values that have them. This is less code then adding them to the dates that do have them. That will allow for a join between the 2 tables.

#### See [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )

Sql with a join

```
SELECT table2.DateWithDash -- add additional columns here as needed
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.DateNoDash = REPLACE(table2.DateWithDash, '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same concerns noted by Igor under your question.  You should consider those carefully.  But those aside...

Append the left four-most digits to the 5th and 6th digits followed by the two right-most digits...

```
    declare @datestring as varchar(8) = '20141101'

    select left(@datestring,4) + '-' + substring(@datestring,6,2) + '-' + right(@datestring,2)
```

This method falls apart if the shape of your input data changes.